# Google Places Autocomplete Elements Show Up Behind Of Sweet Alert

Tags: .net, google-places-api, sweetalert2, google-places-autocomplete

I've been trying to use autocomplete api on sweet alert but couldn't figure out the problem i've faced. Already gave 'z-index: 10000 !important;' style to my input a.k.a search box. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzyB4.png)

The elements should've been in under of input, not behind of swal.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Okay this hasn't worked before i don't know why. Maybe i changed the css/style since then that i can't remember. This seems to fixed the problem.

```
<style>.pac-container { z-index: 9999 !important; } </style>
```

Also got

```
autocomplete="off"
```

in my html elements.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3sOw.png)